# I'm blanking on a word regarding rhythmic interpretation (making 4/4 sound like 3/4 and vice versa)

Tags: terminology, rhythm, time-signatures, meter

I know it's not polyrhythm or anything along poly-whatever lines (I could be wrong, but nothing's ringing a bell) and the only results I'm getting are either like that or not related to my question to at all. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you thinking of *hemiola*?

Comment: If you're not happy with the existing answers, could you possibly be thinking of the words SWING, SHUFFLE and STRAIGHT? These are directions to do with the _division_ of the beat, rather than the _number_ of beats per bar? They can't make "4/4 sound like 3/4", but they can divide each beat into three - or roughly three - changing the feel of the piece completely.

Comment: Can you give any more details on exactly what kind of "making X sound like Y" you're thinking of, or even give examples? You're getting a lot of answers but depending on the context different ones might be best. I might even just go for "metric subversion," depending.

Comment: Maybe link some songs on youtube you know have this "effect", or possibly make a video on your own.

Answer (score 1):

There are some specific rhythms like hemiola and sesquialtera.   But generally, I think you just need 'cross-rhythm'.

Answer (score 0):

Hemiola springs to mind. However, that's less than half the story. A hemiola in *pitch* is the same as the interval of P5 (confusing?), whereas a hemiola in *timing* is  typically 2 groups of 3 beats, replaced by3 groups of 2 beats. Thus retaining the same value per bar (measure), but changing the 'feel' between triple and duple.

Sesquialtera is a far less common term, alternately used (rarely) as the name for a particular organ stop (confusing again?), but also can be, but rarely, referring to the same timing change. It more commonly gets used when music changes time signature - as in 3/4 to 4/4, where the 4 remains at the same tempo. Not exactly what the question is asking, I think, where the *bar* length remains the same for 3/4 and 4/4..

Answer (score 0):

Three things come to mind.

Hemiola...

[image]

...where the eighth notes are first grouped by 3 and then switch to grouping by 2. The duration of an eighth note does not change, but the sense of beat pulses quickens.

Tuplets...

[image]

...where quarter notes play the beat, but at the tuplet 3 quarter notes get squeezed into the duration of 2, and so the pulse seems to quicken.

And duple meter 4/4 compared with 4/4 with triplets, or 12/8...

[image]

[image]

...where the 4 beats to each measure can be the same for all three examples, but the beat division can be by 2 (or 4) or by 3. In this case the 12/8 can have a very clear sense of 4 beats per measure, and so seem like common time. The similarity of 12/8 and triplets in 4/4 is a fairly common discussion topic.

Technically 12/8 is compound meter while triplets in 4/4 is simple duple meter. The difference is really a matter of written notation. With triplets in 4/4 the subdivision of beats by 3 might make someone feel, or actual count 1, 2, 3 for each beat, and that might make someone think of those meters as analogous to some kind of triple (3/4) or compound (12/8) meter, even though they are not.

Answer (score 0):

**Metric modulation** maybe?

Check out this video: [Everybody wants to rule the world](https://youtu.be/_B4Zt_51Yiw)

Also check out this video: [Nautilus](https://youtu.be/Vajhs2wBeCU)  This is so clever - you hear the swinging pattern at the beginning and make assumptions about where the barlines are. It's only when the drums come in at the end that you realise your initial assumption was miles off.